# How can I read a value from a second file sh in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I'm setting up a solution to capture information from cellular router. In my script, I have a `main.sh` launching other files (*.sh) depending on the router model.

So if I want to capture information about cisco router, I execute `main.sh` which is executing `InformationCisco.sh`.

In the last shell file, I have to read a value but

```
  read -p
or 
  echo -n then read
```

don't work.

main.sh

```
./InformationCisco.sh
```

**EDIT :** InformationCisco.sh

```
sshpass -p "$MDPssh" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@"$IPaddress"  "cat /proc/net/arp" > "$MACtxt"
testMAC=$(awk 'NR==3{print $4}' $MACtxt | cut -d ' ' -f23)

if [ -z "$testMAC" ]; then

    MacAddressPlayer=$(awk 'NR==2{print $4}' $MACtxt | cut -d ' ' -f23)
    echo "MAC address Player : $MacAddressPlayer"

else

    echo "2 MAC address in ARP"
    echo "You have to find the correct MAC address for the player"
    cat $MACtxt
    read -p "Enter the right MAC address : " MacAddressPlayer
    MAC_Choice $typeMAC
    echo "MAC address Player : $MacAddressPlayer"

fi
```

I read the ARP table of my router to capture the device connected to it. To do it, I use sshpass where I can enter my password (don't worry my password is not clear, it's just a simplification).
Read function does not stop when is in a second running shell file.

What should I change so the read will wait for an input?

Comment: It works for me. Please give more details that could explain your difference.

Comment: is InformationCisco.sh actually a bash script ? (or anothe shell flavor ?)

Comment: replace InformationCisco.sh with this and try:-while read -p "info : " info; do echo "$info"; done

Comment: I have to keep InformationCisco.sh in order to simplify and let my code be clear, @GopikaBG. Thanks for your answer !

Comment: What is the first line of InformationCisco.sh? Maybe something like #!/bin/something...

Comment: If your script does not stop at `read -p`, it may be because it goes into the first branch of the `if`. What is printed on the terminal?

Comment: My first line : #!/bin/bash and I execute the code thanks to ./ @user803422

Comment: @user803422 I see "2 MAC address in ARP" when I am running the code, so the script is good. It is only about read -p...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be possible that in your context some character `\n` has already been sent to the stdin of the process, and the `read -p` immediately consumes it.

Answer (score 0):

In main.sh try:

```
source InformationCisco.sh
```

That way it won't run the script in a separate process (which might not be connected to your session).